# Integration by parts formula for the double Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

In my research the following  integration by parts formula for the double Riemann-Stieltjes integral
 $$\int\limits_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}f(x,y)\,dg(x,y)=f(b,d)g(b,d)-f(a,d)g(a,d)-f(b,c)g(b,c)+f(a,c)g(a,c)$$
 $$-\int\limits_{[a,b]\times[c,d]}g(x,y)\,df(x,y)
 $$
was applied. One may assume $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ smooth, then $dg(x,y)=g''_{x,y}(x,y)dxdy$ and analogously $df(x,y)$  in the above, but I needed its general version.

I proved it under the conditions $V(f,a,b,c,d)<\infty$ and $V(g,a,b,c,d)<\infty$ and the continuity of $f(x,y)$ on $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, where the total variation $$V(h,a,b,c,d):=\sup\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{j=k}|h(x_i,y_j)-h(x_{i-1},y_j)-h(x_i,y_{j-1})+h(x_{i-1},y_{j-1})|$$
and the supremum is taken over all the partitions of the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$: $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b,\,c=y_0<y_1<\dots<y_k=d$. My proof is in the style of Theorem 6.30 from Rudin, Walter , Principles of mathematical analysis (Second ed.), New York: McGraw-Hill (1964).
My [Google search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=eX6nXM_mH5KurgTGh4-ICQ&q=double%20Riemann-Stieltjes%20integral&oq=double%20Riemann-Stieltjes%20integral&gs_l=psy-ab.12...5962.37577..46719...0.0..0.179.2816.12j15......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131j0j0i67j0i22i30j0i10i19j0i13i10i30i19j0i22i30i19j0i22i10i30i19j0i19j0i13i30j0i8i13i30j33i160j33i21.hXegvLBVq6Y) does not bring that formula, but I am not sure the one is a new result. Any references and comments are welcome.

Comment: Under your bounded variation condition, the formula holds, more generally, for the double Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals (by an application of the Fubini theorem). Also, with minor adjustments (say, by using the right-continuous regularization), you can get rid for the continuity condition for $f$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Thank you for your interest to the question and suggestions. I am not sure concerning your " you can get rid for the continuity condition for $f$" since there are problems in the one-dimensional case when $f$ an $g$ have discontinuity at the same point. Can you give a reference to the formula under consideration?

Comment: The down-vote  should be motivated.

Comment: For one-dimensional RS integral the integration by parts formula holds on the level of Riemann-Stieltjes sums (for any RS sum in LHS there is RS in RHS equal to it, by Abel transform). I do not know what the double RS integral is, but maybe the similar thing happens for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to a comment by the OP: In the one-dimensional case you can write the following, using Fubini:
\begin{align}
 \int_{(a,b]}dg(x)f(x+)
 &=\int_{(a,b]}dg(x)\Big(f(a+)+\int_{(a,x]}df(y)\Big) \\ 
 &=f(a+)[g(b+)-g(a+)]+\int_{(a,b]}dg(x)\int_{(a,x]}df(y) \\ 
 &=f(a+)[g(b+)-g(a+)]+\int_{(a,b]}df(y)\int_{[y,b]}dg(x) \\ 
 &=f(a+)[g(b+)-g(a+)]+\int_{(a,b]}df(y)[g(b+)-g(y-)] \\ 
 &=f(a+)[g(b+)-g(a+)]+[f(b+)-f(a+)]g(b+)-\int_{(a,b]}df(y)g(y-) \\ 
 &=(fg)(b+)-(fg)(a+)-\int_{(a,b]}df(y)g(y-).  
\end{align}
Here the integrals are of course Lebesgue--Stieltjes. 
In the higher-dimensional case, you can do similarly, but with more writing.

Comment: It is not so simple. How do you define "right regularization" in the two-dimensional case? Next, right regularization can change the value of the integral. Also see Exercise 3 in the Rudin's book https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9gj1rr5ss035si/p%20138.docx?dl=0  which shows that the continuity cannot be got rid. Thank you anyway.